# How does spring manage the complete lifecycle of a prototype bean?

Tags: java, spring, prototype, javabeans, lifecycle

How spring manages the life cycle of prototype beans? If it is not calling the destroy method for prototype beans?

Answer (score 0):

Prototype bean utilizes a prototype pattern in the background:

> Prototype pattern allows us to hide the complexity of making new
>   instances from the client. The concept is to copy an existing object
>   rather than creating a new instance from scratch, something that may
>   include costly operations. The existing object acts as a prototype and
>   contains the state of the object. The newly copied object may change
>   same properties only if required. This approach saves costly resources
>   and time, especially when the object creation is a heavy process.

On top of that application managed context objects use AOP, they are wrapped in proxy objects. In the case of prototype scoped bean the underlying aspect delegates the creation of the bean to the spring based implementation of this Pattern.